# viewgroup.getWidth() и getHeight() возвращает 0

Tags: android, height, width, android-view

в методе `oncreate` получается ширина и высота родительского контейнера `imageView`:

```
 RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) imageView.getParent();
        int relWidth = rel.getWidth();
        int relHeight = rel.getHeight();
```

и обе переменные возвращают 0.

С чем это может быть связано?

Родительский контейнер `RelativeLayout` в макете имеет высоту и ширину `match_parent`. Приложение запускается, `imageView` на экране отображается корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема заключается в том, что вам нужно подождать фазы отрисовки для получения реальных значений (особенно с динамическими значениями, такими как `wrap_content` или `match_parent`). Поэтому вам нужно обходное решение для ожидания пока все отрисуется.